# Converting back to Mac OSX

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, iso, macbook, macosx

My friend recently took my early 2007 MacBook and replaced OS X with Ubuntu. I need OS X back. I have the `.iso` for OS X Lion, now what? Please help, as my knowledge of computers is limited.

Comment: What I'd do is to boot from ubuntu live usb or cd, use gparted, errase the ubuntu partition, and then boot from OSX usb or cd and install that

Comment: We're sorry, but this site is all about Ubuntu and the people here are very good at dual-booting and removing OS X, but not very good at getting it back once it was removed...  However, on http://apple.stackexchange.com, a sister site to AskUbuntu, they're very good at deleting Ubuntu and installing OS X, so you might be better off there.  ;-)

Comment: Make a bootable os x istallation disk, insert and reboot your mac, after the startup chime hold c-key (to boot from cd/dvd). After that the .iso image will boot and you can choose `disk-utility` to format/erase the previous os of the hdd. After that simply install os x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Burn it to a DVD or USB/pendrive USB.
2. Go to the boot menu if you can. If you don't have, then go to the grub menu to then select the DVD/USB/pendrive USB. Grub menu can also use just a iso file. Which means you could skip step 1!
3. Do the setup and select it to install over Ubuntu.
4. Reboot, you should now go to OS X.
5. If it doesn't and shows instead a `no OS found` or a blinking underscore, try again.